# Is it legal to pass the address of a temporary to a function with a pointer argument

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Is it legal to pass the address of a temporary object to a function that takes a pointer. If not, where in the standard does it say this is UB. Specifically, I would like confirmation that the following code is legal and doesn't contain undefined behavior:

```
#include <memory>
template <class T>
inline const T* unsafe_addressof(const T&& x) {
    return std::addressof(x);
}

struct S {};

// NOTE: p only used until f returns.
void f(const S* p);

int main() {
    f(unsafe_addressof(S{}));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, it is. You wont be arrested.

Comment: @SvSv Are you sure about that? Somebody might write a compiler which frames the programmer for a heinous crime on any UB. I don’t *think* this has UB, though.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584824/guaranteed-lifetime-of-temporary-in-c

Comment: or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506793/c-life-span-of-temporary-arguments

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280688/taking-the-address-of-a-temporary-object

Comment: It's intentionally hard to do... as you note you have to wrap your call to std::addressof in order to make the compiler work. And that's a good thing - this is about language ergonomics.
The issue here is about contracts. If you control both pieces of code, this seems fine, but... why? Why not just take it by value in f? You wouldn't have any copies, and the lifetime would be the same.

And if you don't control both pieces of code... don't do it. This is depending on a not-great assumption.

Comment: @wrhall addressof was modified in C++17 to make it harder.  Prior to C++17, simply calling `std::addressof` worked I believe.

Comment: @wrhall I don't control f(), however I don't get your argument why not to do it. If f() lets the pointer escape, then its breaking its contract. And I don't really have a choice. If I used a temporary variable instead, it doesn't help the situation at all.

Comment: Imagine f is a factory method that returns a result [clearly not true here, but bear with me]. In that case, it would be reasonable for it to take a ptr and store it on the object it creates.
If you used a temp that were at scope, then both objects would have the same scope and the new one created by f would be destructed first.

Comment: @wrhall and then you return the object and you have issue again. ;-) Of course you must know what the lifetimes are and what references what... On the other hand, what about the argument that passing a temporary directly into a function and avoiding an additional local variable makes the code more readable because it is documenting at the call site that the pointer/reference cannot be used outside of the function otherwise the program would be ill formed.?

Comment: @kalc it's not necessary for you to return it. You might use it locally [but largely we agree on this, I think]. re: "avoid... additional local variable" - I see the point. You could accomplish this with scopes, but that adds a bunch of whitespace / doesn't necessarily *look* better. Ultimately, if it seems like `f` should own the variable, then it should take it by value or take a unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and you don't even have to make it `const`.

```
template <class T>
inline std::remove_reference_t<T>* unsafe_addressof(T&& x) {
    return std::addressof(x);
}

struct S {};

// NOTE: p only used until f returns.
void f(const S* p);

int main() {
    f(unsafe_addressof(S{}));
    return 0;
}
```

Now `unsafe_addressof` will return a pointer-to-array, pointer-to-temporary, pointer-to-lvalue, or whatever else you try to get it to return a pointer to.

The lifetime of that pointer's validity is the lifetime of the thing pointed to, be it a temporary instantiated out of a prvalue, an xvalue, or an lvalue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the advantage of remove_reference here? std::addressof() doesn't use remove_reference.

Comment: @kalc I do not recall what happrns when you take a pointer to a reference, and don't care to learn.  ;)

Comment: I think it Just Works TM. The references will be removed when T is combined with *.

Comment: @kalc That is the kind of thing I'd have to test and read the standard to check.

Comment: I'm unsure either. I think it would call the garbage collector first and then take the pointer to the reference, to ensure the referee is not dead. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb garbage collector??

Comment: @kalc as I said, I'm not sure. maybe Yakk can say something about it?