# Problem with std::vector and/or polymorphism

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I looked everywhere for an answer but can't find one. Below is my short program in visual studio 2017.
It does not print neither of the "rooms" I added - it posts random values. 
The code compiles perfectly. just the output is wrong.
Most the code is irrelevant I think, I just honestly don't know WHAT I did wrong. I think its probably in the vector/inheritance parts.

**EDIT: SOLVED quickly. I inserted a local variable's pointer to my vector. thanks.**

Room.h :

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class Room {
protected:
    int i;
    int j;
    int size;
    char** objs;

public:
    Room(int _i = 0, int _j = 0, int _size = 0);
    int get_i() const { return i; }
    int get_j() const { return j; }
    int get_size() const { return size; }
    char** get_objs() const { return objs; }
    virtual void make_room() = 0;
};

class Maze : public Room {
public:
    Maze(int _i, int _j, int _size);
    void make_room();
};

class Board {
    std::vector<Room*> rooms;

public:
    Board() {}
    void add_room(int i, int j, int v);
    void print_a_room() const;
};
```

Room.cpp:

```
#include "room.h"
#include <iostream>

Room::Room(int _i, int _j, int _size) : i(_i), j(_j), size(_size) {
    objs = new char*[_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
        objs[i] = new char[_size];
        for (int j = 0; j < _size; j++) {
            objs[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

Maze::Maze(int _i, int _j, int _size) : Room(_i, _j, _size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            objs[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
    make_room();
}

void Maze::make_room() {
    int x = 1;
}

void Board::add_room(int i, int j, int v) {
    rooms.push_back(&Maze(i, j, v));
}

void Board::print_a_room() const {
    Room* r = rooms.back();
    std::cout << r->get_i() << "," << r->get_j() << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "room.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Board b;
    b.add_room(1, 2, 10);
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    b.add_room(3, 4, 5);
    b.print_a_room();
    return 0;
}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `rooms.push_back(&Maze(i, j, v));` looks suspicious.

Comment: you're right. its a local variable. I didn't even consider that .... stupid mistake. thanks.

Comment: @Itai Instead of editing the question and saying that you've solved the problem, accept one of the answers below that gave you the solution.

Comment: Up the warning levels of your compiler, I suggest.

Comment: I will look for guides on upping the warning levels, yea. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't compile in the first place ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280688/taking-the-address-of-a-temporary-object)), but since your compiler apparently allows it...

You are storing adresses of temporary objects:

```
void Board::add_room(int i, int j, int v) {
    rooms.push_back(&Maze(i, j, v));   // <---- There
}
```

The `Maze` objects created in this expression die immediately after the expression ends and you're left with dangling pointers, pointing nowhere in particular.

It's usualy not needed to store pointers in a vector unless you want polymorphic behaviour. In that case, use a suitable smart pointer, such as `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: It's ok to store pointers to rooms. just pass a pointer to dynamically allocated object (via new). If the vector will be storing Rooms by value the [object slicing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c/) will happen.

Comment: @Zak Right, haven't thought abou their class structure. Will edit.

Comment: thanks! for some reason I forgot about the whole local-variable scope thing. will try to remember from now on.

Comment: @rustyx Because it's taking the address of an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this: `rooms.push_back(&Maze(i, j, v))`

The problem is that the current object is allocated on the stack, and after this line, this object would be destroyed.

Changing from `Room*` to `Room` is NOT a solution - you cannot have polymorphism if you do this.

Best solution: 
`rooms.push_back(new Maze(i, j, v))`.

NOTE:
You need to define the Rule of Three, because there is shared memory.
When you do a `pop_back`, first call operator `delete` on current element of room, then call `pop_back` method of `std::vector`.

Comment: thanks! I do need to remember to delete it before I pop it. and I will change it to new.

Comment: yea I read that a lot. smart pointers will make it so I dont need to manually delete stuff right? (unless I allocated a 2d array)